# Key Combination to Make All Instances of App the Same Window Size

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

Is there a default Mac OSX key combination that'll make all of my open windows/instances for a given application the same dimension (height/width)? Is there a way to do this with [`Automator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)) (not experienced with it enough to know if it's doable)? Or, an [`AppleScript`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) script that I could initiate using a "hot-key" combination?

**Scenario**: I have multiple instances of the notes app open and would like to resize them to some arbitrary size, preferably stacked staggered on top of each-other.

**From**:

[image]

**To**:

[image]

Comment: Not sure about Automator, but AppleScript handles Windows pretty well.

Comment: @IronCraftMan just updated the question. hopefully someone's already solved this and can provide a solution.

Comment: Take a look at this website: [https://macosxautomation.com/applescript](https://macosxautomation.com/applescript).